# In a Silverlight 4 OOB App how to restore the Window Size and Position without jump

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

I cannot not find any way to restore the Saved Window Position without seeing the Window jump from its initial default Position to the Restored Position. The problem is that the first time I get access to the Window its already visible to the user. Am I missing something or is there currently no way to do this?

Comment: Can you give a codesnippet of where you're doing this right now?

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting OOB Settings, Width=1, Height=1

It is not ideal, but tolerable. 
The window opens very small, then resizes correctly.

I also found that when restoring the window position, you have to set the Width and Height first, then Top and Left. Otherwise there appears to be a bug which sometimes resets the top or left.